# What is the best way to modify the soft-max function to give highest probability on the smallest value in a list?

Tags: python, machine-learning, statistics

I tried to first scale and multiply the values in the list by -1 that coverts the minimum to a maximum. In the code `revsoftMax(data_)` function returns the maximum probability for the minimum value. However, exponential functions are less sensitive in the negative region. Thus, I am looking for more effective solutions.

```
def revsoftMax(data_):
    data = [-x/max(data_) for x in data_]
    return softMax(data)

def softMax(data):
    exp_data = [math.exp(x) for x in data]
    probability = [x/sum(exp_data) for x in exp_data]
    return np.array(probability)
```

Comment: Interesting, but since this is more of a discussion about the approach, you might have more luck on stats.stackexchange.com or datascience.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Have you considered just using `1 - softmax`?

Comment: Have you find an answer? Because I am looking for the same thing and 1-softmax doesn't work: [8,5,0] -> softmax=[0.9523,0.0474,0.0003] -> 1-softmax =[0.0477,0.9526,0.9997] and the values of this second vector doesnt add up to 1

Comment: Though 1- softmax has few limitations, still, I am going with it. @BengiKoseoglu

Answer (score 0):

you can try this  :

```
      softMax(-data)
```

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate in addition to help solve the problem.